# Is there a way to overwrite text with different text using HTML, CSS etc?

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is a stupid question or not.

Is there any way to overwrite text in HTML/CSS with a different text?

An example of what I mean

[image]

I want to make it obvious it's a terrible reskin of a previous website.

I know I could do it with an image, but I'd like to have it as regular text. Is it something you'd have to do with custom fonts? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic example to achieve this.

The content that you really want to display is in the `:after` of the `span` that surrounds the year.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.year {
  position: relative;
}

.year:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: .1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  content: '2021';
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
}
```

```html
<h1>Happy <span class="year">2020</span> anniversary!</h1>
```